# Turn desktop as server to play Counter Strike Source

Tags: counter-strike

Is there a way to make my Desktop (running Windows 7 Pro) to a server and install Counter Strike Source then I can play with my friends online?
Thank you :-)

Comment: I installed from here: [link]https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD Everything is ok, but how do I do for my friends connect to my desktop IP? xx.xx.xxx.xx:27015 and not 192.168.1.106:27015?

Comment: did you configure port forwarding in your router?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

You are looking for a dedicated server.

If you want to make it reachable for your friends you will need to configure port forwarding in your router and setup dyndns.

This video might help you

Video Summary:

1. Download and start `steamcmd`
2. Set directory: force_install_dir c:\csgo-ds\
3. Login: login anonymous
4. Download CSGO-DS: app_update 740 validate
5. Batch file to launch the DS: filename.bat

Ports to open:

- 27015 TCP/UDP
- 27020 UDP
- 27005 UDP
- 51840 UDP

Comment: You should summarize the video's information; that way, if ever it gets removed, your answer is still valid.

Comment: a downvote for that? just because i havent watched the video yet?

Comment: A downvote for answering the question with a video, and not actually explaining what to do.  Videos can be supplemental material, but should not be used to actually answer the question.

Comment: @Frank there you go

Comment: Its tempting to downvote for admitting you posted a video without watching it yet in order to get  a quick answer. Server setup guides make more sense in text format especially as they usually involve some degree of copy and paste (ports etc...).

Comment: ok. i thought i'll provide at least the video so OP can start working. won't do that again.

Comment: Its worth noting that you can also install a source dedicated server from the tools section on steam. The ports will still need to be configured in the same way.